# css don't display text between html elements

Tags: html, css

**Set-up**

I have a piece of HTML that looks like,

```html
<label for="offeringID_0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="offeringID[]" id="offeringID_0" class="active" value="4268" checked="checked">
        <span class="product-name">
            This product: JSDA JD6500                         
        </span>
        "-"
        <span class="price">
            <del>
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    # irrelevant span content
                </span>
            </del>
        </span>
    </label>
```

which renders fine.

---

**Question**

Is it possible to remove the `"-"` with the use of CSS? I'm not sure how to do this.

I've tried `display:none;` on the `<label for="offeringID_0">` element, but then none of the content inside the element get's displayed.

Comment: Who has add "-" in code?

Comment: you could set the color to label and span differently to get out a solution, but its not possible to remove the code with the help of CSS

Comment: @Hkachhia, the developer of this WooCommerce plug-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `font-size:0px` with `label` like below

```css
label {  
  font-size: 0;  
}
label>* {  
  font-size: 16px;  
}
label del{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="offeringID_0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offeringID[]" id="offeringID_0" class="active" value="4268" checked="checked">
    <span class="product-name">
        This product: JSDA JD6500                         
    </span>
    "-"
    <span class="price">
        <del>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                # irrelevant span content
            </span>
        </del>
    </span>
</label>
```

Comment: This seems to go somewhere! Thanks. Nevertheless, I do need the `# irrelevant span content` to be displayed (I thought it to be irrelevant to the question, my bad). Do you know how to adjust your code to make it display that? If so, do you need to know the html of the irrelevant content?

Comment: Do you want to show  '# irrelevant span content' without line-through?

Comment: Yes, no line-through

Comment: @LucSpan Check Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove `"-"` using CSS because it does not belong inside any element alone. Inside the label {in which it currently resides} there are many more elements which all be get affected by the css.
Put the `"-"` in a `span`

```
<span class="removeThis">"-"</span>


.removeThis
{
display:none;
}



 or



label > .removeThis
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to change anything in the html, coz if he does why not just remove `"-"` entirely, what's the point of having it?

Comment: CSS targets the whole element or it's child elements. I don't think there is any other way of doing this. CSS is for styling not for editing content.

Answer (score 0):

You can't realy remove it, but you can hide it. 
If you color it the same as the background, and move the proice slightly to the left, it should look like it's been removed.

```css
label{
  color: #FFFFFF;  /* make all label text white, hiding everything, including the dash */
}

label>*{
  color: #000000; /* revealing all elements except the dash */
}

label .price{
  margin-left: -20px; /* move the price slightly to the left, to accomodate for the hidden dash */
}
```

```html
<label for="offeringID_0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offeringID[]" id="offeringID_0" class="active" value="4268" checked="checked">
    <span class="product-name">
        This product: JSDA JD6500                         
    </span>
    "-"
    <span class="price">
        <del>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                # irrelevant span content
            </span>
        </del>
    </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can't remove it, but u can hack it, if u can wrap it in a span then it is simple see second part , or the hacki solution change font size to 0 then restore font size for everything else.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
}

label * {
  font-size: 15px;
}





label .hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="offeringID_0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offeringID[]" id="offeringID_0" class="active" value="4268" checked="checked">
    <span class="product-name">
        This product: JSDA JD6500                         
    </span>
    <span class="hide">"-"</span>
    <span class="price">
        <del>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                # irrelevant span content
            </span>
        </del>
    </span>
</label>


<label for="offeringID_0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offeringID[]" id="offeringID_0" class="active" value="4268" checked="checked">
    <span class="product-name">
        This product: JSDA JD6500                         
    </span>
    "-"
    <span class="price">
        <del>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                # irrelevant span content
            </span>
        </del>
    </span>
</label>
```

Comment: I think, you should read the comments and other answers before answering

Comment: @JoykalInfotech if you refer to that my answer is combination of other answers posted in 1 minute before me then sorry that i don't compulsively check if someone answered before me

Comment: Not that your answers are combination but you haven't properly understood the problerm, like other

Answer (score 0):

you cannot manage the "-" alone since it not alone wrapped with a html tag. May be you can visually hide it with a matching color with background or some other tricks. But then you have to again apply the reversing css to the sibling elements like span, input etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can by putting the - into a span and add this css!

Hope this helps!!

```css
span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="offeringID_0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offeringID[]" id="offeringID_0" class="active" value="4268" checked="checked">
    <span class="product-name">
        This product: JSDA JD6500                         
    </span>
    <span>"-"</span>
    <span class="price">
        <del>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                # irrelevant span content
            </span>
        </del>
    </span>
</label>
```

Comment: This is not what he can change, he is looking for an alternative.